# Cloudflare scraping, finding elements

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, cloudflare

I have been playing with the cfscrape module which allows you to bypass the cloudflare captcha protection on sites... I have accessed the page's contents but can't seem to get my code to work, instead the whole HTML is printed. I'm only trying to find keywords within the `<span class="availability">`

```
import urllib2
import cfscrape
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from lxml import etree
import smtplib
import urllib2, sys
scraper = cfscrape.CloudflareScraper()
url = "http://www.sneakersnstuff.com/en/product/25698/adidas-stan-smith-gtx"
req = scraper.get(url).content


try:
    page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    print("hi")
    content = e.fp.read() 


soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")
result = soup.find_all("span", {"class":"availability"})
```

I have omitted some irrelevant parts of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try:
    page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    content = page.read()
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    print("hi")
```

You should read the urlopen's object which contain the html code.

and you should put the `content` variable before the except.

Comment: are you familiar with the `ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine` error? Not sure why I am getting this..

Comment: @ColeWorld you should post other question rather than asking new question in the comment. And please accept this answer to close this question.